# How can i set cookie for background changer code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, background

Here is the code for what I need to set the cookie.Is a body background image changer and i want to set cookies to expire in x days!
No matter if is javascript or jquery cookies!

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 

        $("li.one").click( function(){ $
  ("body").removeClass('bg2 , bg3 , bg4 , bg5 , bg6 , bg7 ,bg8').addClass("bg1");
 });

 $("li.two").click( function(){ $
  ("body").removeClass("bg1 , bg3 , bg4 , bg5 , bg6 , bg7 , bg8").addClass("bg2");
 });

 $("li.three").click( function(){ $
  ("body").removeClass("bg1 , bg2 , bg4 , bg5 , bg6 , bg7 , bg8").addClass("bg3");
 }); 

        $("li.four").click( function(){ $
  ("body").removeClass('bg1 , bg2 , bg3 , bg5 , bg6 , bg7 , bg8').addClass("bg4");
 });
  
          $("li.five").click( function(){ $
  ("body").removeClass('bg1 , bg2 , bg3 , bg4 , bg6 , bg7 , bg8').addClass("bg5");
 });
  
            $("li.six").click( function(){ $
  ("body").removeClass('bg1 , bg2 , bg3 , bg4 , bg5 , bg7 , bg8').addClass("bg6");
 });
  
              $("li.seven").click( function(){ $
  ("body").removeClass('bg1 , bg2 , bg3 , bg4 , bg5 , bg6 , bg8').addClass("bg7");
 });
  
                $("li.eight").click( function(){ $
  ("body").removeClass('bg1 , bg2 , bg3 , bg4 , bg5 , bg6 , bg7').addClass("bg8");
 });

});
</script>
```

```html
<ul id="foxycode-panel_bg_image">
 <li class="one"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="two"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="three"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="four"><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
 
................
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for a way to set cookie for n days. You can use the following function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setCookie(cookieName,cookieValue,nDays) {
    var today = new Date();
    var expire = new Date();
    if (nDays==null || nDays==0) nDays=1;
    expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*nDays);
    document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue)+ ";expires="+expire.toGMTString();
}
</script>
and to get the cookie, you can use
<script type="text/javascript">
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i].trim();
        if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
</script>
```

works perfect for me.

Comment: I don't understand how the cookie works! I must to edit you code with smt or I just copy your code?

Comment: Just add these functions to your page and invoke the function when you have to set a cookie like :

setCookie(cookieName,cookieValue,nDays);

where the first argument is cookie name, second argument is the value that the cookie holds and third is the number of days you want the cookie to persist.

Comment: can you post the code for my script because i try but...nothing! Make me to understand pls!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [jQuery cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) like

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $lis = $("#foxycode-panel_bg_image li");
    var classes = $lis.map(function () {
        return $(this).data('class')
    }).get()

    $lis.click(function () {
        $("body").removeClass(classes.join(' ')).addClass($(this).data('class'));

        $.cookie('background-class', $(this).data('class'), {
            expires: 7
        });
    });

    var clazz = $.cookie('background-class');
    if (clazz) {
        $("body").addClass(clazz)
    }

});
```

```css
.bg1 {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
.bg2 {
    background-color: #00ff00;
}
.bg3 {
    background-color: #0000ff;
}
.bg4 {
    background-color: #0ffff0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
<ul id="foxycode-panel_bg_image">
    <li class="one" data-class="bg1"><a href="#">bg1</a></li>
    <li class="two" data-class="bg2"><a href="#">bg2</a></li>
    <li class="three" data-class="bg3"><a href="#">bg3</a></li>
    <li class="four" data-class="bg4"><a href="#">bg4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ujruy52e/)

Comment: Sorry but i have another code in the same page for the background color! how can i make to work together? the codes are the same only the id name is different: #foxycode-panel_bg_color ! I want to work in the same time!

Comment: @FoxyCode sorry... what do you mean..... can you edit the fiddle to recreate your scenario

Comment: My code is a background changer panel! I have background image with transparent texture and background color! My code works perfect, so i set the background color and the background image(transparent texture) comes over the color! The both codes(backgroun image and background color) are the same,ONLY the ID NAME are different! If I insert your code,works fine and cookie is ok but only for background image! If i make the same for background color code,work also but separate! I mean, i can set only the background image or only the background color not together how works without your code !

Comment: PS: SORRY FOR MY ENGLISH :)